# Running powershell scripts from within a .NET windows app

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows

I'm needing to run scripts from within a vb.net windows app.

I've got the scripts running in the background fine;

```
 Using MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
      MyRunSpace.Open()
      Using MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
        MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("import-module -name " & moduleName &
                              vbCrLf &
                              "(get-module -name " & moduleName & ").version")


        Dim results = MyPipeline.Invoke()
        'Do something with the results
      End Using

      MyRunSpace.Close()
    End Using
```

However, i now need to be able to have the powershell run (not in the background)  eg.  When prompts occur;

> ```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
> ```

I'm currently looking into the Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost namespace to see if i can use something like;

```
Dim config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create
ConsoleShell.Start(config, "Windows PowerShell", "", New String() {""})
```

Can anyone advise me please???

EDIT: I've fudged it a bit with this;

```
  Public Function RunPowershellViaShell(ByVal scriptText As String) As Integer
    Dim execProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim psScriptTextArg = "-NoExit -Command ""& get-module -list"""
    'Dim psScriptTextArg = "-NoExit -Command ""& set-executionPolicy unrestricted"""
    'Dim psScriptTextArg = ""-NoExit -Command """ & scriptText & """"

    execProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory & "\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\"
    execProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
    execProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = psScriptTextArg
    execProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Return execProcess.Start
  End Function
```

But there's gotta be a better way??

Answer (score 4):

There is a distinction between the PowerShell engine and its host.  What you're wanting is to run the engine within your application but then fire up a separate host (which also is hosting the PowerShell engine) to handle prompts.  You might want to look into modifying your application to act as a host itself.  You could then react to prompts (read-host) and pop dialog boxes or whatever.  Take a look at this [relevant PowerShell namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms569891(v=VS.85).aspx).  Also check out this [blog post on creating a simple PSHost](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/07/06/windows-powershell-through-ironruby-writing-a-custom-pshost.aspx).