# How to run Powershell scripts in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, powershell, exchange-server

I need to run an Exchange 2007 powershell script in VB.Net, but I can't seem to find a method that shows how to do it with the module loaded.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: This question might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617651/powershell-via-vb-net-which-method-and-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run powershell scripts in VB, take a look at the following link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2008/07/26/calling-a-powershell-script-from-your-net-code.aspx

The link posted above takes you step by step on how to accomplish this.

**Check out this question that relates to yours:**
[Running powershell scripts from within a .NET windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352933/running-powershell-scripts-from-within-a-net-windows-app)

This following article is in C# but should help you understand the concept a bit better:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET try this code:

```
Process.Start("powershell", "-File C:\YourFileLocation")
```

Basically, all you're doing is calling PowerShell and specifying an argument (the location of the cmdlet you're calling).