# Get-AppxPackage command doesn't work when being launched by my application (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, powershell

My application's purpose is to run the GetAppxPackage code in PowerShell to install an user preferenced package (so for example feedback hub).

The Powershell command is as follows:

**get-appxpackage -allusers *feedback* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}**

(There are asterisks left and right of feedback, but stackoverflow makes it italicized)

The above code runs normally in Powershell, when manually opening Powershell and running it.

The following code Iam using to run in it VB.NET

```
Dim w3 As String = "feedback"

Clipboard.SetText("get-appxpackage -allusers *" & w3 & "* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register " & Chr(34) & "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" & Chr(34) & "}")

Process.Start("powershell.exe", "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *" & w3 & "* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register " & Chr(34) & "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" & Chr(34) & "}")
```

The clipboard is not neccesary obviously, but I used it to confirm the code is exactly the same as it should be.

Powershell outputs the following (when being launched from my application):

Add-AppxPackage : A Positional Parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\AppXManifest.xml'
At line:1 char:49
+ ... | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -Disabledevelopmentmode -Register $($_.In ...
+
+ Categoryinfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-AppxPackage]. ParameterBindingexception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound.Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

My application is running with Administrative rights, and so is Powershell.

Do not know what the problem is, or could be, since the code is exactly the same. Would really appreciate any help towards solving this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Process-Start and the native Start-Process all have very specific quoting requirements, especially when multiple arguments are needed.

For example:

```
Process.Start("Powershell.exe", @"""ScriptwithArguments.ps1"" 'arg1' 'arg2 asdf'")
```

You will also see arguments that use comma separation.

I am also not real sure as to why you have all the ASCII codes, for a single PowerShell one-liner command and the normal string quotes. Which is native PowerShell would be just this.

Start-Process -FilePath Powershell -ArgumentList "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | ForEach{ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml -WhatIf}"

So, your...

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *" & w3 & "* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register " & Chr(34) & "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" & Chr(34) & "}")
```

… should just be this, because you only have one argument, that entire command string.

```
Process.Start('powershell.exe',"Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | ForEach{ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $($_.InstallLocation)\\AppxManifest.xml}")
```

See also these discussions as well for more edification...

[How to run Powershell scripts in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782121/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-in-vb-net)

[Running powershell scripts from within a .NET windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352933/running-powershell-scripts-from-within-a-net-windows-app)

[Calling a PowerShell Script From Your .NET Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2008/07/26/calling-a-powershell-script-from-your-net-code/)

[Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c) This would be similar in VB.Net of course.

[Process.​Start  Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: To clarify, I used the ASCII codes because the 'original' PowerShell code has "" in them, which also end (and start) a string in VB.NET. I tried your method, and using just one argument in this line, it didn't work. Also your argument is different, you forget "" and doesn't seem to even work in PowerShell, no offense. These links you added for edification are not discussing this problem. I can't seem to find any solution online, and I've visited a lot of sites. Not trying to be an asshole, but do you have any more idea's, on how to solve this?

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that I wrote the 'Uninstall function' in my application. Which is Process.Start("powershell.exe", "get-appxpackage *" & w3 & "* | remove-appxpackage"). This command seems to work fine. I get that PowerShell accepts one argument in this case, but even in my original code, in my post, the code gets passed on to PowerShell as one argument only.